# angular 5 and firebase/angularfire, using keys to check if key is present in another table

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I have a situation in my database (screenshots attached) Where a user can have 1 or many courses associated with them, I'm using their key as the key in the table as below.

[image]

[image]

As you can see the key ending in Dpof2 is in both tables and has access to launchpad.

Now I've written some code which creates an array of all of the keys in the /courses table using the reference of 'launchpad' or 'independence'.

This returns the array fine, but from here I've run into problems doing the comparison and getting the users that match the keys in the array.

Here is my code in the .ts file

```
getCourses(course) {

this.courses = this.getCourseKeys(course);

if (this.courses.length > 0) {
  let test = [];

  let users = this.adminService.getUsers();
  let usersLength = 0;
  users.subscribe(snapshots => {
    usersLength = snapshots.length;
    console.log(usersLength);
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      for (let i = 0; i < usersLength; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.courseKeys.length; j++) {
          if (this.courses[j] === snapshot.$key[i]) {
            test.push(snapshot);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    console.log('user data');
    console.log(test)
  });
}
}

private getCourseKeys(course): Promise<any> {
this.courseKeys = [];
this.courses = this.adminService.getUsersCourses(course).subscribe(snapshots =>
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    this.courseKeys.push(snapshot.$key);
    console.log(this.courseKeys)
  })
);
return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
  return this.courseKeys;
});
}
```

This is the getUsers function from the service, but I dont know if it matters.

```
public getUsers(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
this.userId = this.auth.currentUserId;
return this.auth.currentUserDetails(this.userId).switchMap(snapshot => {
  this.foyer = snapshot.foyer;
  this.access = snapshot.access;
  if (this.access !== 'superadmin') {
    return this.db.list('/users', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'foyer',
        equalTo: this.foyer
      }
    });
  } else {
    return this.db.list('/users');
  }
}) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
}
```

I've tried multiple things and now stuck trying to get the getCourses() function to wait for the getCourseKeys to complete. Currently it returns an error saying the return is illegal from getCourseKeys. I'm at the limit of my firebase/angular2 knowledge so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the magic of angularfire2 is that it allows you to work with the super handy Observables with the power of rxjs operators, instead of the classic promiss-based APIs that the Firebase SDK for the web offers. Angular works amazing with observables, so I'll encourage you to do it with Observables. Also, by the way you should update angularfire2 to the latest version, which is how I'll show it to you. If you want, there is another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234431/querying-angularfire2-database-flattened-data) on data relationships that I've also anwered.

So let me assume that you have modeled your data with interfaces like:

```
interface User {
    uid: string;
    name: string;
    // Or whatever
}

interface Course {
    identifier: string; //  Like launchpad, independence
    // Or whatever
}
```

Now pay attention to the helper methods that you can put into your service:

```
getCourse(identifier: string): Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.db
    .object<Course>(`/coursesListSomewhere/${identifier}`)
    .valueChanges();
}

// And this method is the crucial one which
// will give the exact array of Course objects
// That this user has been subscribed to,
// So you can do whatever you want with them,
getCourseListForUser(uid: string): Observable<Course> {
    return this.db
    .list(`/courses/${uid}`)
    .snapshotChanges() // This emmits an array of snapshots
    .map(snapshots => {
        return snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.key)
    }) // Here we map each snapshot to the key, so we get an array
    // of course identifiers, which we'll switchmap to the actual courses
    .switchMap((coursesIdentifierArray: string[]) => {
        // Some rxjs and array transformation so the final Observable
        // will emmit the Course[] array for this particular user
        return Observable.combineLatest(
            coursesIdentifierArray.map(this.getCourse)
        ).map(Array.prototype.concat);
    })
}
```

No if in some component you want to have the courses array for some inputted userUid string, you can get the courses observable like this:

```
@Input() userUid: string;

courses$: Observable<Course[]>;

constructor(someService: SomeService) {
    this.courses$ = this.someService.getCourseListForUser(this.userUid);
}
```

And then easily unwrap with the async pipe into your template with whatever way you want:

```
<div *ngFor="let course in courses$ | async">
  {{ course | json }}
</div>
```

I hope this helps and I wish you good luck with your app!

Comment: That's incredibly helpful and I Appreciate the time you've taken to answer the question, do you know of any resources I could use to help better understand observables/rxjs etc?

Comment: Well you can always be checking the official documentation http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html or personally I really like the Angular Firebase channel on YouTube that's more specific for Firebase will Angular

Comment: Just what i needed